# Can I rotate in a 3dish way a group tag in an SVG file?

Tags: svg, 3d, rotation

Can I rotate in a 3dish way a group tag in an  SVG file?

Is there any need for an external JS library? I'd be glad to get a link somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently 3d support isn't here yet so you have to make it look like there is three dimensions.

Have a look at the following links, they explain in detail how to use SVG to give a 3d effect.

[rotating cube - wireframe (looks like 3d with controls to move it)](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/blog/rotating-3d-svg-cube)

[3d animation - advanced animation in 3d](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/blog/3d-animation-svg)